# How to pass 'filename' parameter to FormData.append() method for string data

Tags: multipartform-data, form-data

In my `FormData.append` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append%28%29) I have some job settings that I send as part of multipart/form-data `POST`. The problem is: my case is the third one, as specified in the link above, that is - I pass my data as a string (and not as `file` or `blob`), and therefore, I cannot specify the third, optional parameter `filename`.

Is there a workaround of how I could specify that additional parameter for the string data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no method to modify `FormData` to make it add a `filename` header field unless you use `File`. There isn't even a method to read data from `FormData`, so it's quite a restricted object. **However, you can construct a `File` object with the string you need and pass that to `FormData.append`.** Like such:

```
var fileStringArray = [ "Foo bar" ];
var fileName = "...";
var blobAttrs = { type: "text/plain", ... };
var file = new File(fileStringArray, fileName, blobAttrs);

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file1", file, file.name);
```

Check out the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object pages on MDN.

Answer (score 2):

I completely forgot about posting this one :)

In the end of the day I went for the solution that used `Blob`:

```
var jsonFD = JSON.stringify($scope.jsonResult.analysis);
var jsonFile = new Blob([jsonFD], {type: 'text/plain'} );
fd.append('upload', jsonFile, 'jobSettings.json');
xhr.open("POST", $scope.hostPdf);
```

Which is essentially what you suggest :)

Thank you.